# How to add images on splash screen in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, splash-screen

I just created a software using a vb.net(2010) and its work fine. I need to add a splash-screen to that. I can add the splash-screen using the "add new item" but i need to modify that (in-built splash screen) **i want to add a picture and change the name version etc**..
can you please help me with that issue.
Thank you
Pasindu Mallikaarachchi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have added a splash screen via add new item, go to the properties of the Layout panel on the splash screen (to do this, you may right click on the splash screen on the designer rather than the splash screen file in solution explorer).

In the properties find BackgroundImage and click the button to change properties for background image,

[image: selecting new splash image]

you will now get a wizard that will ask you for selecting a resource file either from one of the files included in solution explorer or from local storage. Selecting any image will replace the default splash image. You may also change the BackgroundImageLayout property to suit your choice.